# The function $\beta$-truncation is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Consider a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{X})$. Let $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be an arbitrary extended real-valued measurable function on $X$. For each positive real number $\beta$ define the *$\beta$-truncation* of $f$ as the real-valued function $f_\beta:X\to\mathbb{R}$ on $X$ defined for each $x\in X$ by
>   $$f_\beta(x)=\begin{cases}f(x),&\text{if }|f(x)|\leq\beta,\\\beta,&\text{if }f(x)>\beta,\\-\beta,&\text{if }f(x)<-\beta.\end{cases}$$
>   Show that $f_\beta$ is a measurable function.

I have this question on my mind for a while, but no ideia came to me for calculating $f^{-1}_\beta((\alpha,+\infty))=\{x\in X: f_\beta(x)>\alpha\}$. Could you give me some tip ?

I managed to define the sets $A=f^{-1}((-\infty,\beta])\cap f^{-1}([-\beta,+\infty)),B=f^{-1}((\beta,+\infty))$ and $C=f^{-1}((-\infty,-\beta))$, from where we can express the function $f_\beta$ as $$f_\beta(x)=f(x)\chi_A+\beta\chi_B-\beta\chi_C.$$
Since $f$ is measurable $\Rightarrow$ $A,B$ and $C$ are $\mathcal{X}$-measurable $\Rightarrow$ $f_\beta$ measurable, because it is the sum of measure functions.

Comment: What is the question? You have proved neatly that $f_{\beta}$ is measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Basically "How to 'calculate' by hand the set $f^{-1}_\beta((\alpha,+\infty))$ ?"

Comment: There is no need for that. Use the theorem which says that products and sums of measurable functions are measurable.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach:

Define $g_\beta:\bar{\mathbb{R}} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
-\beta &\text{ if } x<-\beta\\
x &\text{ if } |x|\leq-\beta\\
\beta &\text{ if } x>\beta
\end{cases}.$$

$g_\beta$ is measurable because it is continuous.

Then $f_\beta = g_\beta\circ f$ is also measurable, because it is the composition of measurable functions.